# How to fix 'Creating default object from empty value' in Laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

In blade I have this code:

```
@foreach ($employees as $key => $employee)
<tr id="{{$employee->id}}">
<td class="visibleemployee tdcenter">
<form action="{{route('admin.employees.cambiarVisible',$employee->id)}}">
  <button type="button" id="buttonchangevisible" data-id="{{$employee->id}}">
    @if ($employee->public == '1')
        <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true" id="margindataemployee" class="cambiarsiporno"></i>
    @else
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" id="margindataemployee"></i>
    @endif
  </button>
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
 </form>
 </td>
 </tr>
 @endforeach
```

When I click the bottom the Ajax function is executed:

```
$("#buttonchangevisible").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var button = $(this);
        var id = button.data('id');
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url:'employee/cambiarVisible/' + id,
            type: 'PUT',
            data: formData,
            success: function() {
                location.reload();
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        return false;
    });
```

And call to the next method:

```
public function cambiarVisible(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $employee = Worker::find($id);
        if ($employee->public = 0){
            DB::table('workers')->where('id',$id)
            ->first()
            ->$employee->public = 1; 
        }
        else{
            $employee->public = 0;
        }
        $employee->save();
    }
```

Now don't appear any error, if I click in first row, make the call but don't the update of visible.

But if I click in other row, don't make the call.

Comment: `if ($employee->visible = 0)` should be `if ($employee->visible == 0)`

Comment: Your ajax url should give the real id instead of `{id}`. It sould be like `employee/cambiarVisible/10` not `employee/cambiarVisible/{id}`. You got the error because $id passed in `cambiarVisible()` is string. Just try `dd` it.

Comment: @JiFus now I get this error: `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: can you share your web route code ?

Comment: About the error you get: `->first()->$employee->visible = 1` should probably be `->first()->visible = 1`.

Comment: LluísPuigFerrer This is because of the issue mentioned by @DharmaSaputra

Comment: The problem is that is it a Form with different data with different ID @DharmaSaputra

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a similar piece of code.
I generated the form dynamically, then called some JavaScript/jQuery.

Code to generate the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-block deleteUserBtn" data-name="{{ $user->name }}" data-id="{{ $user->id }}" data-type="delete" onclick="return false;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
```

Then using the following code, I executed the ajax call. The reason the click event is attached to the body is because there are multiple delete buttons (this was for an user overview with multiple delete buttons, one for every user). And these buttons can be generated with jQuery, the click event will not fire if you bind to the buttons.

```
$('body').on('click', '.deleteUserBtn', function() {
    var button = $(this) // Button that triggered the event
    var id = button.data('id');
    var name = button.data('name');
    var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val(); // This token is already on the page, you need a token to prevent csrf

    if( confirm('Are you sure you want to delete: ' + name + '?') ) {
        var url = "{{ route('overview.users.destroy', ':id') }}";
        url = url.replace(':id', id);
        $.ajax({
            method: "DELETE",
            url: url,
            data: {
                'id': id,
                '_token': csrf
            },
        }).done(function(response) {
            // Check if it is successful
            if(response == 'deleted') {
                // Reload page
                location.reload();
            } else {
                alert('error');
                console.log(response);
            }
        }).fail(function(response) {
            alert('error 2');
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
});
```

As you can see I just passed the id as a parameter.

In your case, to update the user, you can just use the following piece of code:

```
public function cambiarVisible(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $employee = Worker::findOrFail($id);
        $employee->public = ($employee->public == 1) ? 0 : 1;
        $employee->save();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, now pass the ID in first row. Can you check my question again?

Comment: It works perfect but only in first row. Can you explain this line? `$employee->public = ($employee->public == 1) ? 0 : 1;`

Comment: I can't use ID, if I change `$("#buttonchangevisible").click` to `$(".buttonchangevisible").click` works!

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer The second line is a [ternary if statement](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

Comment: @LluísPuigFerrer Is it working for you, or do you still need help?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your form has a ajax submit which is using `employee/cambiarVisible/{id}` as URL. since the `id` wildcard is supposed to be a php variable (cannot see the variable in JS), it's not being passed to the controller.

Try something like

`var id =  {!! json_encode($employee->id) !!};`

Then change the url as

`url:'employee/cambiarVisible/' + id,`